# Programmatically replace text and image in psd file

Tags: javascript, node.js, .net-core, photoshop, psd

I have a psd file provided by a designer.
I would like to use this psd file as a template to generate images.

I tried to use **psd.js** to make the changes in a react application. I successfully read the file, parsed it and found the text layer I was searching for but i wasn't able to change the text and generate an image with my changes.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have a website where a user can directly update the text and export the result into an image.

Do you have any  idea how I can achieve this ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you'd have to delete the particular block and than add your own in its place. Keep in mind that, despite Adobe's efforts to meet customer demand, PDF files aren't really meant to be edited. You should instead edit the document from which the PDF was originally created and then generate a new PDF.

Comment: By doing this I'll have to ensure a full copy the design that was applied on this layer.
The perfect solution would be to have a [link](https://www.photopea.com/) where I allow only text editing for specified text

Comment: `theLayer.textItem.contents` in javascript is the text layer which you'll want to change, bearing in mind you can only change plain text, no bold or italics.

Comment: I  already tried this property but when exporting it into an image, the base text is still applied

Comment: @ImadBenAbdeslam Hi, I too want to automate changing content only. Can you add the sample code which will be useful for me ?